# Getting Complete Contact's Phone Number With Country Code, Even if Country Code is Not Entered

Tags: java, android, country-codes, libphonenumber, mobile-country-code

I am working on an app where have a login activity, in which, when the user logs in, it automatically saves contacts from their phone to the server. This works, but I have one issue, when I save the numbers they are saved in the format the user entered in their phone. For example if the user entered this number: +15555555 it will be saved like that, but if he entered it without country code it will look like this: 5555555, without the +1, or any other country code depending on the country.

***What I want to is to return all of my contacts with their country code, even those that user have entered without the country code.***

Some apps like Viber can recognize the format it is in, so if it doesn't start with +1, or starts with 05.., it is recognized and it automatically adds the country code, so that 05.. becomes +15...

```
public void updateContacts() {

    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    String userId = user.get("uid");

    if (phones != null) {
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            if (phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER) != -1) {
                final String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                Call<ContactsResponse> call = apiService.contactExists(phoneNumber, userId);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ContactsResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ContactsResponse> response) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "abc");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ContactsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (phones != null) {
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

I am using libphonenumber, so I was wondering if there is a way to use this and get the country code, then add it to the number without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. If a user does not type in a country code or area code, then when that number is called the service provider will automatically assume that they are using the country code/area code that they are currently in. If you have 518-222-2345 saved and you call this number in the US, the service provider will add a +1 to the beginning. If the user then takes a trip to the UK and tries calling the same number(contact-entry), the service provider will add a +44 code to the front. Long story short the data that you see is all the data that is stored on the device and when that specific data(country-code/area-code) is not there, the service provider assumes the codes of where they currently are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. Is there a way to add my country code to the phone if the user doesn't have it, or is there a libphone trick that can help? I think apps like Viber do something like this.

Comment: Hi @Banana. How do you open your problem? Can you help me, please?